# How to make a radio button fully toggleable?

Tags: android, radio-button, toggle

I've been changing over some app menu options lately in order to simplify the graphics and give me more space to work with. I added a radio button, and have it set up to toggle on and off when pressed via a listener:

```
                View.OnClickListener toggleListener = view -> {
                Settings.getSetting().toggleSetting();
                holder.settingToggleButton.setChecked(!holder.settingToggleButton.isChecked());
                };

                ...
                holder.settingToggleButton.setOnClickListener(toggleListener);
```

But when I load into my app and toggle the button, it'll work initially (options that are on get toggled off, and vice versa) but when I then try to tap it again and toggle the option back on/off, it doesn't work. It sticks either on or off, whichever state it was initially toggled into when I first pressed it. I'm not sure why this is happening, as the logic is very straight-forward... any ideas as to why this set up isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to my question; it's a niche solution related directly to my problem, but overall, it was indeed related to not checking for/modifying the ID of the toggle button. If you're ever having issues with the button toggling one way but not the other, or not toggling at all, make sure all references to that button, and all the changes it's involved in, take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
 holder.settingToggleButton.setChecked(!holder.settingToggleButton.isChecked());
```

The logic here is correct, as @Ansh suggested, I would say the problem is the UI never receives the setChecked attribute and what you're seeing is the default behavior of a radiobutton, which takes the initial input but isn't toggleable without logic code.

If you think that's not the case, try putting down a Button that updates the toggle state of a specific radiobutton. This'll help you see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The holder is what handles/updates the UI based on the setting option selected, using that toggleListener (hence holder.settingToggleButton ... the button's ID is referenced). The logic in place all worked when there were two buttons (On/Off), and I've tried changing the logic from setChecked() to toggle() as well as applying a radio button style to a CheckBox even, still have the same results.

Comment: Glad you solved it, if my answer is correct please vote and accept as answer, I'm still locked out of commenting on others' answers due to my lack of reputation.